# Could not execute php script command line

Tags: php

I am using xampp and windows OS. I am trying to execute simple php script command line but I got an error like "Could not open input file http://test.localhost.com/test.php". Below is my code for the same.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php  
<?php  
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');  
while (true) {  
        $input = fgets($stdin, 3);  
        if ($input == 42) {  
                break;  
        } else {  
                echo $input;  
        }  
}  
fclose($stdin);  
exit;
```

I giving me above error. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: How are you executing this script?

Comment: Why would you be using a UNIX hashbang and UNIX path to PHP if you're on Windows?

Comment: Your post contradicts itself.  Are you running from the command line or in your browser?  If you are running it from the command line, then specify the file name, not a URL.

Comment: It seems you want to run a CLI php in browser. Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call a CLI script, not a website.

```
c:/path/to/php.exe c:/path/to/scrip.php
```